# Rails validate model attribute based on value of another attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a rails app with User model which has state and city attributes.
I am using a gem to get the list of cities of a given state and country.
I want that while signing up if the city selected by user is not in the list of cities for the state selected by user then dont allow signup and show error.

```
  validates :state, presence: true, inclusion: { in: CS.states(:in).keys.collect{|x| x.to_s } }
  validates :city, presence: true, inclusion: { in: CS.cities((:state).to_sym, :in) }
```

I wrote this code in user.rb model but its not working.
`:state` should refer to the value submitted by user for 'state' attribute but i don't think that's working here.
I want to pass the value of state given by user to the function `CS.cities()`.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a proc or lambda object which gets the current user instance. This instance you can ask for the state. The proc or lambda should return an enumerable with all valid cities.

adapted from the [rails v3.2 api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_inclusion_of):

```
validates :city, presence: true, inclusion: { :in => lambda{ |user| CS.cities(user.state.to_sym, :in) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `before_save` filter :

```
:before_save :check_city_state

def check_city_state
 unless CS.cities((:state).to_sym).include?(self.city)
  self.errors.add(:city, "select city within the selected state.")
  return
 end
end
```